# In-App purchases on Mac Store

Tags: ios, macos

I am trying to get a populated response to my app's *SKProductsRequest*, but the *SKProductsResponse*s come back with 0 results. So this leads me to believe I've set the In-App purchases up incorrectly in iTunes Connect.

First, do you have to submit an app binary to test your In-App purchases for the Mac App Store? That doesn't make much sense but this statement on iTunes Connect makes me think that, specifically "your first in-app purchase must be submitted with a new app version":

[image]

Secondly, the "In-App Purchases section" has no "Submit" button, and you can't **select** an In-App purchase (it's just text). What is it the statement referring to when it says "select it from the app's in-app purchases..."?

[image]

My app has the In-App purchases entitlement, I've verified that the SKProductRequest requests a valid product name, and I also have a paid applications contract in effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that I had to follow these steps:

1. Create a Sandbox Tester user for Mac App store
2. Log into developer.apple.com using that Sandbox Tester account

then the *SKProductsResponse* is populated as expected.

Answer (score 0):

You have to simply submit upload a new build of your App using Xcode to iTunes Connect, then it will work. As simple as that.

Regards